# How to set default branch policies for future branches in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I want to lock release branches from merging anything. Adding a default branch policy is fine as well. I can do it for any existing branch but not future branches.
Is there a way to set default branch policies?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open your Branches page on Azure Devops, you will see **...** icon next to branch names. If you click them, there are options related to that branch but if you do it next to a folder then it is related to a wildcard now.

Click **Branch policies** in that menu and you will see the title on the next page as **"Policies for: ProjectName > RepoName > release/*"**

Now, you could set any policy and the other branches in that folder will inherit them. It works for the new branches as well.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to find a solution for future repos as well. Turns out there are
**cross-repo policies** :)

Goto:

*Settings > All Repos > Policies (tab) > **scroll down** to add new policies*

You can add wildcards too :)

Actually took me a while to find. Maybe it helps someone.

[image: devops policies tab]

Comment: I can't find this in Azure Devops at all. There' no 'settings' page, nor all repos, nor policies. The policies tab is only there for each separate repository's settings.

Comment: klick the little gear icon bottom left. There should be a "Repositories" entry. See the screenshot that I added. Once you reach the policies tab, you have to scroll *all the way* downwards

Comment: Will try on Monday and get back to you. Thanks for replying :)